# How do I setup web pages within Azure Service Fabric Stateless Web API?

Tags: azure

I am using VS 2017 and have successfully setup to use Stateless Web API. I can see the output of the default controller when I run it.

Now, I want to create web pages within this project and use AngularJS SPA within it to access its own API.

I am unable to find any examples which clearly show how to do this. Note this is ASP.NET Web API - not ASP.NET Core.

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Microsoft and this can be done with the ASP.NET Web API support in service fabric. Web pages can be added to the self-hosted web api project, but each file has to be individually configured for this project - if you have hundreds of files, it does not allow you to configure the entire folder contents for the project, because you have to mark each file to build as content. The example they sent me is an obscure article in a Microsoft blog from a Microsoft Engineer nobody has heard of before.

Not worth it. Use the ASP.NET Core support.